# Detached HEAD in Git and confusing conflicts when rebasing

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two fresh checkouts of remote branches, one branch (`crm-mania`) is a couple of months old and I am attempting to rebase it onto the main development branch (`master`). So I have the following:

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (crm-mania)$git branch
* crm-mania
  master
```

I then do the following:

```
    vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (crm-mania)$git checkout master
    Switched to branch 'master'
    vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (master)$git pull
    Already up-to-date.
```

Then I try the rebase and I get the following (amongst other messages that I have chopped out):

```
    vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (master)$git rebase master crm-mania
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: CRM-174: Mania Site
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       app/AppKernel.php
M       app/config/config.yml
M       app/config/routing_crmpicco.yml
<stdin>:107: trailing whitespace.
<?php
<stdin>:108: trailing whitespace.
/**
<stdin>:109: trailing whitespace.
 * @author    CRMPicco <crmpicco@crmpicco.co.uk>
<stdin>:110: trailing whitespace.
 * @date      02/04/2015
<stdin>:111: trailing whitespace.
 * @copyright Copyright (c) CRMPicco.
warning: squelched 1022 whitespace errors
warning: 1027 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/config/routing_crmpicco.yml
Auto-merging app/config/config.yml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/config/config.yml
Auto-merging app/AppKernel.php
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 CRM-174: Mania Site
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /var/www/releases/20150708141200/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

The main issue I have is that **the HEAD is now detached**, e.g.

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (HEAD)$git status
# HEAD detached at e90cb5c
```

I also find that if I ignore this message and try and work through my conflicts that Git is recognising "conflicts" in code that only I have worked on and only reside in my `crm-mania` feature branch. They are definitely NOT in the `master` branch.

Comment: You are NOT going to rebase already pushed branches on master. This will screw up history for other contributer.

Comment: @ckruczek `master` is the main development branch and `crm-mania` is the feature branch. I am the only person who will be working on `crm-mania` so I won't screw up the history for anyone. What I am trying to do is bring in all the latest work (around 2 months worth) from master and replay my work on top of it. Can you see why I would have this problem with a detached HEAD?

Comment: Hmm I am not pretty sure why there is a detached HEAD, could you please supply more information. Like, more output? Because your output seems totally fine for me for the moment.

Comment: @ckruczek I have updated my question with the full output from the rebase. Is it an issue that I have rebased this feature branch onto master in the past? It shouldn't be AFAIK, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Ahh thats more clear now. You have to solve the merge contlicts and move on with git rebase continue

Comment: @ckruczek I'm familar with resolving conflicts during a rebase, however that doesn't solve the problem of having a detached HEAD and why I have conflicts in files that only exist in the `crm-mania` feature branch.

Comment: `git rebase` always puts you in detached head while it applies the commits.  That's just how it works.

Comment: @AndrewC Thank you, I didn't realise this. Based on the comments to this post it looks like i'm not the only one. Feel free to submit an answer and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main issue I have is that the HEAD is now detached

This is expected behavior.  The way that `git rebase` works is by directly checking out the destination SHA, which puts you in detached HEAD.  This is coincidentally why `ours` and `theirs` are reversed from normal in the `git rebase` scenario.

Whenever you have a merge conflict during a rebase you will always be in detached HEAD state.  This will also happen if you `edit` any of the commits in an interactive rebase.

As to why you are seeing unexpected conflicts, that is impossible to say without seeing changelogs for the two branches.  Usually the answer is "somebody else modified the code and I didn't realize it".